# Sonar gathering reports from multiple platforms

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I have Jenkins triggering builds and generating analysis reports on several platforms (Win7, Linux and Mac) for C++ code. For the moment, I run Sonar on Ubuntu and I can import all the reports generated on Linux into Sonar. I would like a way to also import the reports generated on other platforms too. How could I do that? What is the "recommanded" way to track cross-platform projects? Should I make one sonar project / platform ?

Comment: What do you mean by "import the reports generated on other platforms"? What do you call "reports"?
What version of SonarQube are you running?
What C++ plugin are you running: the one from SonarSource or the one developed by the community?

Comment: By reports, I mean those produced by cppcheck, unittests, Valgrind, etc. I am running the community C++ plugin.

Comment: @DavidRACODON: I edited my question to add some details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anyone? I believe that it is a common use case. Having a crossplatform project with jenkins needing to gather reports from Linux + Win + Mac for the same project.